# python sender password containing non-ascii-characters

Tags: python, ascii, sender

When I try to send a mail with the sender module and I have non-Ascii-Characters in the password (like §), I get an error:

'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xa7' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)

Is there any way to circumvent this?

Comment: This is caused by a [bug in the smptlib module](https://bugs.python.org/issue29750) which [sender](https://github.com/fengsp/sender/blob/master/sender.py) depends on.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

Due to the comment from @ekhumoro, I just wanted to link to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63102839/i-cant-use-unicode-characters-in-email-password-with-django), whose answer proposes a couple of solutions to the problem you're having (as there is no official solution). The three possible solutions given are:

1. patching the smtplib.py file to use UTF-8 rather than ascii
2. using a different mail client
3. changing your password

**OLD ANSWER:**

looking at [the code for sender.py module](https://github.com/fengsp/sender/blob/master/sender.py) in the sender library, it looks like there is support for UTF-8 now built in. try making sure you're using python 3 and the latest version of the library.

if this still isn't working for you, there is a [fix in this thread](https://github.com/fengsp/sender/issues/3)-- essentially, you change this line in sender.py
`charset.add_charset('utf-8', charset.SHORTEST, None, 'utf-8')`

to this
`charset.add_charset('utf-8', charset.SHORTEST, charset.BASE64, 'utf-8')`

I haven't tried it and can't confirm, let me know if it helps.

Comment: That won't help, because the problem is specific to *passwords*, not message bodies.

Comment: Ah I was wondering. I didn't see that it had smtplib as a dependency.